# vim split next file on command line

Tags: vim, split-window

I often run vim on multiple files eg vim *.cc
sometimes I'm halfway through the list and I'd like to keep editing the current file and then split the window (sometimes vert and sometimes horiz) to the NEXT file on the command line ... # is the last file name and % is the current. I need a next file name

:sp %+1

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. If it can help you, `:ls` will show you all the files and their buffer number. You can use that later number in front of `:b` or `:sb` for example (e.g. `:4sb`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

thought about it a bit more... write the file, goto the next, then split to the last file

```
:wn
:sp #
```

would still be nice to do it in a single command